# Creating Queries in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a query that will display the name of the staff who are not mentoring any other staff. It should also be ordered by the surname.

So far, I've got this:

```
SELECT a.name, m.mentor
FROM accountant AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN accountant AS m ON a.mentor = m.staff_id
WHERE m.mentor = NULL
ORDER BY m.surname;
```

When I run the query it doesn't return any results.

Any help would be nice.

Comment: Show us table structure.

Comment: Any sample data with tables  structure would be nice also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try To Use IS Null Not = Null

```
SELECT a.name, m.mentor
FROM accountant AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN accountant AS m
ON a.mentor = m.staff_id
WHERE m.mentor is NULL ///  here
ORDER BY m.surname;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.name, m.mentor
FROM accountant AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN accountant AS m
ON a.mentor = m.staff_id
WHERE m.mentor IS NULL
ORDER BY m.surname;
```

You need to use [`IS NULL`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx), you cant check if the value is `equals(=)` to `NULL`